# What benefits would the G7 get by creating their own programme in response to the Belt and Road initiative?

Tags: geopolitics, belt-and-road-initiative

What benefits would the G7 get by creating their own programme in response to the Belt and Road initiative? The G7 recently announced its own programme in response to China, but isn't it too costly and playing directly into China's hand by developing countries that are poor since China's plan is to connect poor countries to itself to benefit from their economic growth? What might be a benefit I am not considering, because I don't see much benefits that can benefit the G7?